# How to use Dynaconf to configure Celery

Tags: python, configuration, celery, django-celery

Recently I discovered Dynaconf which is a nice configuration management package that integrates nicely with Flask and Django. The Django app is running wonderfully with Dynaconf. However the Celery app that my App depends on to run background tasks is not.

Here is the code for the configuration of the Celery app that was working before using Dynaconf:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('KillerApp')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

It seems that I need to change 'django.conf:settings' to something else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a string representing a module to import, or just pass in the configuration object directly; see the [`Celery.config_from_object()` method documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.config_from_object).

You'll have a module that sets up the `Dynaconf()` instance, e.g. if you have a package named `acme_project` with a `config.py` file in it with

```
from dynaconf import Dynaconf

settings = Dynaconf(
    settings_files=['settings.toml', '.secrets.toml'],
)
```

then you can import `acme_project.config` and find the `settings` object there. You can either import that object or let Celery do that by using `'acme_project.config:settings'` as the value you pass to `app.config_from_object()`. The `namespace` argument tells Celery to expect all settings to be prefixed with `CELERY_`, exactly like the way this works with Django. Use this if you plan to use the Dynaconf-managed settings to configure multiple components, not just Celery.

E.g., if you used:

```
app.config_from_object('acme_project.config:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

then your `settings.toml` or `settings.yaml` or whatever file format you picked would need to use `CELERY_` as a prefix for all the settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Django plugin for Dynaconf](https://www.dynaconf.com/django/#initialize-the-extension) then you are able to just use the `django.conf:settings` directly as Dynaconf patches the django settings object.

If you still have problems I recommend opening an issue on [dynaconf repo](https://github.com/rochacbruno/dynaconf/issues) and try using the settings of your application directly.

Example, if you have an app called `foo` your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` might be `foo.settings` then you can use for celery:

```
app.config_from_object('foo.settings:settings')
```